# Is the total upwards vertical force (lift included) greater than the weight in a steady climb?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-physics, flight-dynamics, climb

[image: from https://aneedforairspeed.wordpress.com/2009/06/27/climbing-descending/]

Related to questions on [forces](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/40921/21091) in a [climb](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/87497/21091): if any aircraft is climbing with a constant velocity, is the total upwards vertical force (lift included) greater than the weight?

Comment: We already have a question that specifically asks "My question therefore is also about the sum of all vertical forces: in a steady climb, is the total upwards vertical force from all sources (wing, tail, engines, fuselage) larger than, or equal to the weight of the aircraft."  See  [Does lift equal weight in a climb?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/40921/does-lift-equal-weight-in-a-climb)

Comment: The body of the question asks about the total upwards force, which might be construed to mean either the net vertical force excluding weight, or the sum of the *upward* force components.  Since at least one aerodynamic force has a downward component, these are not the same thing.  The title asks about the total vertical force, presumably meaning the net vertical (aerodynamic?) force, i.e. the sum of all vertical forces other than weight. The title and body could use some editing to be better harmonized and be more clear about which of these things you are asking.

Comment: (So consider changing title to read "Is the sum of the upwards forces higher than weight in a steady climb?", or "Is the net vertical aerodynamic force greater than weight in a steady climb?", depending on which you really want to know.)

Comment: Is Lift Greater Than Weight In A Climb was asked 4 years ago, editing it now may make many of the answers a mismatch. It was active again when [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/86939/21091) was added, initially stating that it was. It received quite some downvotes. It is important to realise in the debate that upwards vertical force is higher than weight in a climb, but lift isn't necessarily, depending on the tilt of the aircraft velocity vector.

Comment: It's interesting how vague simple words can end up being-- (I guess that's why a force vector diagram is worth a thousand words) -- I'm still not completely clear whether you are asking about the *net* vertical aerodynamic force, or the *net* vertical force, or you are interested in adding up all the upward aerodynamic force components (while ignoring the downward aerodynamic force components) and comparing that value to the weight-- my answer https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/56476/34686 to the other related question is intended to address all those different cases--

Comment: Come on.. F=ma!  If the net vector acceleration is zero, then the sum of all vector forces must also equal zero. What you call them, or how you break them up into arbitrary components is just picking at nits. If you define and separate them in any way where the sum is NOT zero, then you have done it wrong or missed one or more of them. Remember any scheme used to define all the forces is just sleight of hand... The real physical, actual forces are the force exerted by each molecule of air/gas bouncing off the airframe, and the propeller as it spins, or the turbine in the jet engine, etc. etc.

Comment: The word Upwards has been added in the title, voting to reopen.

Comment: Using a vertical rocket as a model, the answer is obviously *yes*, as vertical drag + weight = "total upwards vertical force" (in a steady state climb).   What made it so interesting all those years ago was replacing the more efficient wing with thrust *to get a higher angle of climb*, and comparing that with using thrust to climb *faster, but at a lower angle*.  Hence the Vx, Vy, cruise climb discussion goes on.

Comment: @quietflyer In your answer at Lift Greater Than Weight, you state: “*In a steady climb, net vertical force must be zero, so net vertical aerodynamic force must be equal to weight.*”. Plus vertical component of drag, as illustrated in the answer.

Comment: @Sanchises Are you happy with the changes now?

Comment: @Koyovis please draw the closed vector diagram (better yet to scale) that shows *thrust that closes the triangle of lift* **plus** thrust that overcomes aerodynamic drag.  Essentially, it's quiet flyers  diagrams plus a "handle on the side" for the equal but opposed drag and thrust vectors.  For all three cases, we can see how *excess thrust* can be used to climb.  Don't forget greater airspeed makes a bigger "handle", steeper climb can be lower speed, smaller lift vector, *but much more use of excess thrust for sin of climb angle*.

Comment: Also remember (for props) excess thrust is greater at lower airspeeds, so yea, it's complicated. Let's go with 2400 lbs of lift (in level flight), 700 lbs of thrust available at Vx, 650 at Vy, and 550 at cruise climb.  Aerodynamic drag 300 lbs at Vx, 250 lbs at Vy, 350 lbs at cruise climb.  See what we get.  The diagrams will yield *angle of climb*, then we can throw V as a Power factor (F × V) to get *rates of climb*.

Comment: As sin angle x V.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni Ehm...that was another question, a couple of them. Point of this one is to acknowledge that not only weight needs to be compensated for by a combination of upward forces. Whichever combination that is, has been answered in [a lot of detail.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/40925/21091).

Comment: Yes, lots.  TL/DR?  Closed vectors *to scale*, haven't seen it, particularly for your question presentation because:  drag at Vx is higher due to less optimal AOA, drag is higher at "cruise" due to less optimal speed.  Vy combines the best of both for highest *rate of climb* which is greatest excess Power as F × V.  We're both preaching to the choir, but it sounds good.  (and we still have that thrust available curve to think about too).

Comment: @Koyovis -- re "@quietflyer In your answer at Lift Greater Than Weight, you state: “In a steady climb, net vertical force must be zero, so net vertical aerodynamic force must be equal to weight.”. Plus vertical component of drag, as illustrated in the answer."  -- no,, in a steady-state climb, *net* vertical aerodynamic force, *the vector sum of all upward and downward aerodynamic components*, must be equal in magnitude to weight (and opposite in direction, of course.)

Answer (score 5):

This question is purely a definition issue, and the answer is 'yes' or 'no' based only on which definitions you use. In Newtonian physics, a lot of complex interactions are modelled as single, lumped vectors which we call "forces". These forces share nice properties with vectors: notably, that we can decompose vectors into multiple vectors, or sum multiple vectors into a single vector. One of the main reasons to do so is to decompose a vector into components parallel to some (typically orthogonal) coordinate system.

An important observation is that there is no 'true' way of representing the forces acting on the airframe. While some decompositions are more popular than other, all are equally valid (if done correctly). I will take two examples, one of which arrives at your conclusion 'yes', the other 'no'.

Example 1. Decompose the aerodynamic forces on the airplane, parallel and orthogonal to the flight path. Call one 'lift', call the other one 'drag'. Let's assume 'thrust' is also parallel to the flightpath. Weight is represented as a single vector, orthogonal to Earth, and is not decomposed along the flight path. Now take all the forces that we decomposed along the flightpath, and *again* decompose them but now orthogonal to Earth. Now, only look at the forces pointing 'up', which in a climb (but not in a descent) removes the vertical component of the  'drag' vector, and compare it to the weight vector. With this elaborate procedure, we can conclude the answer is 'yes'.

Example 2. Combine all aerodynamic forces on the plane in a single vector instead of decomposing them into lift and drag, called the 'net aerodynamic force'. Leave the thrust and weight vector unchanged. Again, we decompose all vectors along the Earth reference frame. Now, we find the sum of all the upward components is exactly the same as weight. We can conclude the answer is 'no'.

[image]
<sup>*Note: the net aerodynamic force is shown in the left diagram for illustration only to show that it is the sum of lift and drag, and is not actually part of the force balance for example 1.*</sup>

Comment: Would [this case](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/87497) be example 2 as well?

Comment: @Koyovis In that case there is no lift, only drag, so there's no difference in the net aerodynamic force and the decomposed lift and drag vectors. If your climb is steep enough, example 2 changes from 'no' to 'yes'. (1/2)

Comment: Either way, this highlights why I wonder what the practical value is of your question at all, because the answer changes according to definitions and flight conditions. What exactly inspired this question? (2/2)

Comment: The downwards pointing drag is there as well in shallow climbs, if small enough like with GA planes it can be neglected. When working with aerodynamics of helicopters & military jets, it is very apparent that this force needs to be considered in questions about lift & climb.

Comment: @ymb1 No idea either. I lumped parasitic drag with the rest of aerodynamic forces, because the point here is to show that the definitions you use to separate the forces acting on the airframe determine the final answer, not to elaborate a complete description of all forces acting on the aircraft.

Comment: This is the right answer, for reasons @Sanchises explains well. It all depends on the definitions. If we are very pedantic about the question, we can see that in a steady-state purely vertical climb that the net thrust is weight PLUS drag. So that's a way to say "yes". But if we get away from the "gotcha" nature of that nuance, then we have a simple Newtonian mechanics problem which stipulates that all forces must balance in steady-state motion.

Comment: @Robert Look at the vector diagrams. They're too scale. Excess thrust is available. Forces balance. What are you saying?

Comment: What I am saying is forces balance *after upward velocity reaches steady state in all cases*.  No need for two diagrams.  Therefor total upwards force equals weight plus vertical drag.  No need to separate rocket case, aircraft case, helicopter case, case 1, case 2...  Amazingly, the answer is a simple modification of the 4 forces they teach in flight school. Even more so, how much more thrust is required to offset tilted vector. (I suspect this may be the real secret to "laminar flow" wings, tilting the lift vector *forwards* a bit).

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni The two diagrams show the exact same case, with the exact same forces, but just represented slightly differently to show that which definitions you use changes the result. Please make an honest effort trying to **understand** what I'm writing instead of jumping to conclusions.

Comment: I'll buy that.  Your diagrams (and Quiet flyers) inspired mine.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

[image]

Vertical forces are forces in the earth axes reference frame. So remaining in this reference frame, assuming $\gamma$ ≈ $\alpha$ in a steady climb, the vertical forces are:

$$W + D \cdot \text{sin }\gamma - L \cdot \text{cos } \gamma - T \cdot \text{sin } \gamma = 0$$

- Pointing downwards = + = $W + D \cdot \text{sin }\gamma$
- Pointing upwards = - = ($L \cdot \text{cos } \gamma + T \cdot \text{sin } \gamma$)

So in order to continue climbing, the total upwards vertical force - consisting of a combination of Thrust and Lift - must be larger than weight by a factor of D * sin $\gamma$

Notes:

1. Upwards aerodynamic force is often called lift. But lift is defined in the airframe aerodynamic axis, and tilts with the direction of the airspeed. So for a fixed wing aeroplane in a steady climb, total vertical force is higher than weight, but lift is smaller than weight.
2. If the upwards force changes, the climb speed changes accordingly. There is an acceleration, causing a change in aerodynamic drag which stops when the forces are in equilibrium again.

Comment: Only in a constant density atmosphere. In reality the airplane loses climb speed with increasing altitude, so there is a vertical deceleration term which reduces the vertical force ever so slightly.

Comment: Lift is NOT total Upwards aerodynamic force! It is the component of all aerodynamic forces perpendicular to the plane formed by the wings and the flight path of the aircraft. If in a climb, then the flight path is inclined upwards and not vertical, so lift (if it to have any same meaning) is also not vertical. You CAN define it any way you want I suppose, but defining it as the vertical component when the aircraft is in a steep climb or descent, (or for that matter a steep bank), serves only one purpose, to confuse.

Comment: @PeterKämpf The plane is also burning fuel, reducing the weight over time as well. The plane in question is climbing at a steady rate.

Comment: @CharlesBretana Thank you for pointing out the value of asking this question twice, once about lift and once about net upwards force. Mentioned in note 1. in the question.

Comment: And what is net upwards force in an F-16 in a pure vertical climb? Do we count the force of the dynamic air pressure on the front surfaces of the aircraft as negative upwards force? what about the force  of air pressure on the rear surfaces of the airframe? They are of course pushing the aircraft upwards. Are they "Lift"?  Breaking up aerodynamic forces into defined components is done to create understanding and simplify and enable calculations. Applying these arbitrary definitions in scenarios where they do not help to do that only confuses.

Comment: @CharlesBretana It’s a matter of axes definition. Above question is referenced in earth axes, avoiding the confusing axes tilt of the aerodynamic reference frame.

Comment: I Guess you could say that. What I'm saying is that how you define terms (what axes you use to define them) not only determines your analysis, but sets the context for the scenario your analysis will be meaningful or useful in. Defining terms inappropriately, (using the "wrong" axes), results in meaningless or useless conclusions. In this case, what is significant is that vectoral acceleration MUST be directly proportional to the vector sum of ALL forces (F=ma)! Any definition of forces or choice of axes that does not clearly show that is pointless or wrong.

Comment: @CharlesBretana In 3 dimensions,  vectorial sums are constructed in each of the 3 axes. The axes are perpedicular to each other. The pic in the question shows the relevant forces in earth axes z-direction, the point being that there are **three** vertical forces, not the two that are usually considered. Note that it depicts the situation at constant velocity airspeed and - climb speed.

Comment: @Koyovis, Actually, vectoral sums can be calculated in any basis set. Cartesian axes are just one of the way to do so. forces can be broken up into components based on polar or spherical axes as well. They don't even really have to be normal to one another (although non-normal choices of axis introduce significant complexities). Also, when all relevant forces lie in a 2-D plane, it is only necessary to perform the calculations based on a choice of two axes that also lie in that plane. There is no need to include a third axes when there are no forces in that dimension.

Comment: @Koyovis,  Finally, the choice of which axes to use when breaking up the forces into vectoral components is critical. Choosing a set of axes that increases the complexity of the necessary calculations, or obfuscates the underlying physics, just because "Those are the standard axes" or "That's the way we always do it", is probably not the optimum way to do engineering. The choice of axes should be based on the problem to be addressed.

Comment: If we take the op's question, as worded, (specifically his use of the word Vertical, then in fact there are actually only TWO dimensions in play here, the vertical axis, (as you say, the z-axis perpendicular to the earth's surface), and a horizontal axis parallel to the aircraft flight path. And there are two forces that need to be broken up into components along those axes. The force imparted by the engine thrust, and the total aerodynamic force on the airframe. The vertical components of these two forces must indeed be equal and opposite to the fictitious "force" of gravity.

Comment: ..plus the vertical component of the airflow resistance.

Comment: Well, yes, But I would include "airflow resistance" as just a part of the "Total Aerodynamic force" on the airframe. We tend to break it up in a myriad of ways, "Lift" vs "Drag", then we break up "Drag" into "Form drag" and "Induced drag", where induced drag is component of total lift that is parallel to the flight path, etc. etc. But in actuality, it's all just the result of air molecules hitting the surface of the airframe.  Each molecule that bounces off the airframe imparts a force normal to the surface at that point, proportional to the molecules change in momentum.

Comment: The total aerodynamic force is just a vectoral sum of all these individual molecular forces, over the entire surface. Then, depending on what problem we are trying to solve, or situation we are trying to understand, we break up this vector sum into multiple components, oriented in directions that make sense for that specific problem or situation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *always*, unless aerodynamic drag does not exist.

For winged aircraft, the above is impossible, therefor the answer is yes, always.

It is important to realize *excess thrust* is required to climb.  Excess thrust closes the weight/lift triangle *but does not account for aerodynamic drag*, which equals the amount of additional thrust required to maintain airspeed.

*Add this "handle" (in the direction of flight) to the closed vector diagram for vertical lift* and voila!  There is your vertical aerodynamic drag component (decomposed from the aerodynamic drag vector).

*Always there*, *in any climb*, for any aircraft.

An aircraft that has a thrust to weight ratio of less than one simply must use a ramp *while maintaining airspeed against drag*.

The combination of excess thrust and lift support the weight, enabling steady state flight with 0 acceleration (from Gravity), while the remaining thrust at a given velocity opposes aerodynamic drag (part of which is being used to create Lift).

[image]

Like this.

In level flight only around 300 lbs of thrust is needed, as the far more efficient wing can now bear all the weight.

Answer (score 1):

If the net forces are zero, the movement will be steady, as per Newton's second law.

If upwards vertical forces equals weight, we will have net zero vertical forces and a no vertical movement (hover).

If the total upward forces are greater than weight we will have a vertical acceleration until drag brings velocity to a steady state.

If *all* vertical forces = weight the aircraft may be rising, hovering, or descending with 0 acceleration.

Comment: Thanks Robert for the edits! Could you check again to see if there is a possible conflict between paragraph two and four. If so, I think it is pragraph four that should be kept.

Comment: In paragraph 2 "downward" force from drag = 0, so 2 and 4 do not conflict.  Please excuse my passion (in editing).  Paragraph 4 covers all 0 vertical acceleration cases, indeed, vertical forces essentially make the plane "weightless" leaving the drag from velocity.  (Now we can think about airships too).

Comment: Ah, I see, drag has a downward component in steady climb. And we presume it is a climb. And we exclude downward compents from upwards vertical forces. Then its the slowest climb = hower. Couldn't it still give the reader the expression that zero force always have to give a standstill and not as in Newtons second a steady movement?

Comment: An object in an environment with drag and 0 net force will slow to 0 velocity. (Unless drag force is included!).  Since we are comparing all upward force to weight, if there is upward velocity, there is a *downward* drag component, therefor...