# Is the Lift required for a steady-state climb and descent equal for the same absolute value of the kinematic climb angle?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, aircraft-physics

Here is my confusion :
I found in my lecture script the following equation for the steady-state climb and descent (*wings level*)

```
L = m*g*cos(gamma) , with gamma being the kinematic climb angle (1)
(equation is simplified neglecting the Thrust angle of attack)
```

Now if an aircraft is flying at the **same indicated airspeed** (IAS) and the **same absolute Vertical Speed** (VS) once a **climb (*positive VS*)** and once a **descent (*negative VS*)**, does it need the **same lift** in both situations ? (*Neglect wind influence*)

The kinematic climb angle should be equal in magnitude, but with flipped sign. According to this equation

```
gamma = asin(V_Vs./V_IAS); (2)
```

After plugging the values into (1) we get the same required Lift. Is therefore the angle of attack (AoA)  equal in the two scenarios ?

Also I assumed that:

```
Theta = AoA + gamma
```

Thank you for your help and clearing up my confusion :)

Comment: Hello Christian Mändle, and welcome aviation.stackexchange.com! Your question will be closed as a duplicate of [Does lift equal weight in a climb?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/40921/19). The answer of [Peter Kämpf addresses lift in descent](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/40923/19) as well. If there are

Comment: This question is clearly not the same as the claimed duplicates.  This question is about whether the effect is the same in climb and in descent.  This is a very reasonable answer because the usual explanation for the lift deficit in climb is that a component of thrust is offsetting the weight -- which is clearly not identically true in descent.

The short answer to the question is Yes.  $L=W\, \cos(\theta)$ does not care the sign of theta.

Comment: Interestingly it is *oppositely* true in a descent:  the vertical component of **drag** is "offsetting" (some) of the weight