Climb angle relationship to excess thrust
In the PHAK, Chapter 5 Aerodynamics, the following statement is made regarding forces in a climb:

The thrust required for a stabilized climb equals drag plus a percentage of weight dependent on the angle of climb. For example, a 10° climb would require thrust to equal drag plus 17 percent of weight.

I believe this is derived using trigonometry, using the sine of the angle of climb. Is this correct? How would one visualize this using a right triangle? Thank you.

Highly related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/56476/34686

Yes,
$\sin(\theta)=\frac{T-D}{W}$
Where $\theta$ is the flight path angle.
Start by drawing a free body diagram of the airplane.  You can draw an airplane, or just a point at the center of mass.
Draw the horizon through the point.
Draw an arrow depicting the velocity vector through the point.  Since we are interested in climb, you want the velocity vector to be 'above' the horizon.  The angle between the horizon and the velocity vector is $\theta$.
Draw the four principal forces, Thrust, Drag, Lift, and Weight.
Lift is perpendicular to velocity.
Drag is parallel to velocity, but pointing in the opposite direction.
Weight points down, perpendicular to the horizon.
Thrust is approximately aligned with the velocity vector.
Now you can start to look at triangles -- or to sum forces.
Your instinct is probably to draw a triangle with legs horizontal and vertical.  That will work, but it is a hassle.
Instead, draw your triangle with the legs parallel and perpendicular to velocity.  You'll see a $W\sin(\theta)$.  That will show you're on the right track.

Good answer. Just a few additional comments. The greek symbol theta is normally used in aerospace engineering for pitch attitude, not flight path angle, which is typically associated with the greek symbol gamma. Also, an assumption baked in to the equation is small angle-of-attack (e.g., less than about 10 degrees).

@AeroAndy Yes gamma is (probably most) frequently used for flight path angle, but it is also used for the ratio of specific heats, which comes into aircraft performance in the equation for the speed of sound.  So, I find that many references will use something other than gamma -- and sometimes that is theta.  It is my preference, but certainly not universal.  You are correct, the small alpha assumption is lumped into the 'Thrust is approximately aligned with the velocity vector'.

For large AOA, you might want to take T*cos(AOA) instead of T, so that both T and D are aligned with the velocity vector, otherwise (T - D) wouldn’t make sense as they are on different axis.
